# Looping an array received from service

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

**JSON from service**

```
{
    "firstname": "Utku",
    "lastname": "Dalmaz",
    "photos": [{
        "src": "image",
        "post_id": "69"
    }, {
        "src": "image",
        "post_id": "74"
    }, {
        "src": "image",
        "post_id": "133"
    }, {
        "src": "image",
        "post_id": "142"
    }]}
```

**SWIFT CODE**

```
Alamofire.request("SERVICE", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        var success = 0
                        if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                                success = successInteger
                                if success == 1
                                {
                                    self.firstname = dictJSON["firstname"] as! String
                                    self.lastname = dictJSON["lastname"] as! String

                                    if let photos = dictJSON["photos"] as! Array<String> {

                                      let postID = //post_id data
                                      let src = //src data

                                      let data = InboxPhotos(ID: postID!, src: src!)
                                      self.photosArr.append(data)
                                    }  
                                   ...
```

I am trying to get array data from JSON service. Even though I am able to get firstname and lastname data, I cannot get and loop photos array in swift code.

How can I loop photos array and get **post_id** and **src** data into **InboxPhotos** and append to photosArr array?

Comment: because it is not an array of strings. It is an array of dictionaries. Try dictJSON["photos"] as! [[String:String]] or dictJSON["photos"] as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I am having Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[[String : String]]'

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to contain an explicit question. What is the expected outcome? [ask]

Comment: @Ferdz I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: FYI you should use Codable for JSON and you can have quicktype.io write the code for you if you just paste the sample data in (pay attention to the optionals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let dictJSON = ...

  guard let photos = dictJSON?["photos"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

  let list = photos.map { InboxPhotos(ID: $0["post_id"] as! String, src: $0["src"] as! String)}

  // Or more safely.
  let list2: [InboxPhotos] = photos.compactMap {
    guard let src = $0["src"] as? String,
      let id = $0["post_id"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }

    return InboxPhotos(ID: id, src: src)
  }
```

Comment: Then should I do self.photosArr.append(list2) ?

Comment: var photosArr: [InboxPhotos] = [InboxPhotos]()

Comment: No. photosArr.removeAll()
  photosArr.append(contentsOf: list)
  
  // or just
  photosArr = list

Answer (score 0):

**I have made JSON parsing modal for your JSON Data-Type. you don't need anything just pass data at the time create a modal object and get data without hectic.**

```
struct UserModal{
        var firstname:String
        var lastname:String
        var photos: [PhotosModal]

init(dictData:[String: Any]) {
    self.firstname = dictData["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
    self.lastname = dictData["lastname"] as? String ?? ""
    var photosArr = [PhotosModal]()
    for data in dictData["photos"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? [] {
        photosArr.append(PhotosModal(src: data["src"] as! String, post_id: data["post_id"] as! Int))
    }
    self.photos = photosArr
}
}

struct PhotosModal{
    var src:String
    var post_id:Int
    init(src:String, post_id:Int) {
        self.src = src
        self.post_id = post_id
    }
}

let userModal = UserModal(dict: dictJSON?["photos"] as? [[String: Any]])
```

So Make separate file for this modal file. Applying this you will follow Single responsibility class/file of **SOLID** principal rules.